Identify SOT23-6 IC, marking 2105BCQQ, Inside mains LED driver
I have SOT23-6 SMD IC with markings code 2105BCQQ



The question text says the IC is in a SOT23-5 package. However, from the picture the IC has 6 pins, which would be a SOT23-6 package. Can the package dimensions be measured to confirm if a SOT23-6 package?

I just compared another ic, sot23-6

I changed the IC BP2329A I bought today and it works without any problems
